# complex search and find in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns in excel.

Column A has a list of 10,000 rows of data.
Column B has 500 rows of text to find in column A

I know I can use formulas like: =IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND(TRIM($C$2:$C$3023),A2),0))>0,"Yes","No")
But this only searches for 1 cell search at a time.

Is there any way I can create a function that searches for any text/numbers found in column C2:C500 and find any of that data in A2:A10000?

Here's a basic image of what i'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following **UDF** (User Defined Function) in a standard module:

```
Public Function IsItThere(rBig As Range, rLittle As Range) As String
    Dim v As String
    IsItThere = "Not Found"
    v = rBig.Value
    For Each r In rLittle
        v2 = r.Value
        If v2 <> "" Then
            If InStr(v, v2) > 0 Then
                IsItThere = "found"
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

To use it, in **B2** enter the formula:

```
=IsItThere(A2,C$2:C$500)
```

and copy down.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=IsItThere(A2,C$2:C$500)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

for specifics on UDFs

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Brilliant! You make it look so simple :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use also a simple formula:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;$C$2:$C$9;1;);0)=0;"No";"Yes")
```

instead or your...